# counter with leading zeros not returning the right result

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Whenever I click, I count from 01 to 10, 01 all the way to 09 works but when it reaches 10 it messes up the number.

I have a function that receives a year variable which is the last 2 numbers of a year ex: 2022, the year for that in my case would be 22. I want to then count from 01 to 10 without removing the leading zeros. My code works once it's larger than 10 but whenever it's at 9 and then hits 10, the year gets a 0 added. This is an example of what the result would look like : 2008, 2009, **20010**. I'm not sure why this happens because I'm only going until 9 and then checking if it's equal to 10...

```
             if (parseInt(strYear) < 10) {
                
                
                location.href = 'calendar.htm?ddlDay=' + numDay + '&ddlMonth=' + numMonth +
                        '&ddlCentury=' + numCentury + '&ddlYear=0' + (parseInt(strYear) + 1)

                
            }
            else if (parseInt(strYear) == 10) {
                
                location.href = 'calendar.htm?ddlDay=' + numDay + '&ddlMonth=' + numMonth +
                    '&ddlCentury=' + numCentury + '&ddlYear=' + parseInt(strYear)
            }
            else if (parseInt(strYear) > 10) {
                
                location.href = 'calendar.htm?ddlDay=' + numDay + '&ddlMonth=' + numMonth +
                    '&ddlCentury=' + numCentury + '&ddlYear=' + (parseInt(strYear) + 1)

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that without those "if" conditions. Check the code below if that produces your desired output...

```
const numDay = 20; const numMonth = 12;
const numCentury = 20; const strYear = 22;

location.href = 'calendar.htm?ddlDay=' + numDay + '&ddlMonth=' + numMonth + '&ddlCentury=' + numCentury + '&ddlYear=' + numCentury + strYear.toString().padStart(2, '0');
```

**Output:** calendar.htm?ddlDay=20&ddlMonth=12&ddlCentury=20&ddlYear=2022